# How to sequence unit test cases in Python unittest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have written automation suite using Python `unittest` which makes use of `HTMLTestRunner`. Test cases are generated at runtime. In this scenario, test cases are executed alphabetically. How can I execute them in particular order?

For example:

Give `test_a`, `test_b`, `test_c`

Current Order: `test_a`, `test_b`, `test_c`

Expected Order: `test_b`, `test_c`, `test_a`

Comment: You shouldn't do that. You should change your testing strategy to be order independent. This may require refactoring your code.

Comment: @Dan You should post this as an answer, possibly with some info (or link) to how to properly structure unit tests?